# with Paperclip can I use different file name for thumb than original?

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I'm using the Paperclip gem in my image hosting project and one of the things I want to do is display the image without sub directories. So they show as mydomain.com/image.jpg However one of the problems I am having is that since I changed the :url option to just ":filename" now whether I display the image using

```
<%= image_tag @user.image.url %> 
or 
<%= image_tag @user.image.url(:thumb) %>
```

It will always display the original image and not the thumb since they both have the same filename. Is there a way I can have the thumb naming convention changed to something like image.t.jpg so that I can make a routing rule to route .t.jpg to display the thumb? If I add :style into the :url option then I get /original/image.jpg and /thumb/image.jpg which is OK for the thumb but I don't want to have the /original/ sub directory for the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using html image tag instead of ruby to display the original image. So the image tag looks like this now:

```
<img src="/<%= @image.image_file_name %>" class="image-display" />
```

instead of

```
<%= image_tag @user.image.url %>
```

Then I left the thumb as the ruby image tag so it displays as root.com/thumb/image.jpg which I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `:url` option to something like `:style_:filename`, it should result into the `"thumb_image.jpg"`

Comment: I tried this but then you also get original_image.jpg. I'm trying to do it like imgur.com where the images are just root.com/image.jpg then thumbs can be image.thumb.jpg or root.com/thumb/image.jpg.